# Count distinct group by SQL code?

Tags: sql, select, distinct

say I had just 2 columns of data....

```
Postcode Sold date
LE14 6QR 01/01/2011
```

How could I say...display for each postcode the date for each time a house in that area has been sold.

E.G If that postcode occurs 14 times, it would list each of the dates?

Thanks,

Comment: If you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint on (Postcode, Sold_date)--and you probably should--then your table won't support data for "each *time* a house in that area has been sold". (Emphasis added.) It would support reporting each *date one or more houses* in that area has been sold.

Answer (score 0):

From you description it sounds like you want to list the contents of the table, so you can do:

```
select Postcode, [Sold date]
from MyTable
```

If you do not want duplicate dates, you can do:

```
select Postcode, [Sold date]
from MyTable
group by Postcode, [Sold date]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to group then you should also COUNT just to make sure you're totals are adding up.

```
SELECT PostCode, [Sold Date], COUNT(PostCode)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY PostCode, [Sold Date]
ORDER BY COUNT(PostCode) DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT PostCode, SoldDate
FROM YourTable
Group By PostCode
```

Comment: -1 - you can't group by one column and not have an aggregation function applied to the other column.  So you either need to group by both or add aggregation (i.e. MAX) for the sold date.